# Delete /svg-inkscape directory with latexmk cleanup

Tags: latexmk, svg, output, cleanup

I'm using the `svg` package to include graphics in my document. When I compile using `latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 "myFile"`, my working directory fills with all of the typically generated LaTeX files (.aux, .log, etc.), but I also get a /svg-inkscape directory.

To clean the generated files, I run `latexmk -c`. This successfully deletes all of the generated files *but* leaves the /svg-inkscape directory—and its contents—untouched.

**How do I configure `latexmk` to delete the /svg-inkscape directory when I run `latexmk -c`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of latexmk, there's no documented way to configure it to do this kind of file and directory deletion.  My inclination in such cases is to write a little script to do clean up: it would call latexmk -c, and then delete whatever other files and directories are to be deleted.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this by putting Perl code into my project's `.latexmkrc` file? Or is there a way to call the script from the `.latexmkrc` file? I'm trying to allow my project configuration to work across platforms, so a shell script might not be ideal.

Comment: Also, could you please consider adding this feature in a future release? It would certainly be very helpful (some other packages also place generated files in a subdirectory).

Comment: There's nothing at all simple you can do in a .latexmkrc file.  There are very non-simple ways, e.g., to override the cleanup subroutine in latexmk.pl with your own modified version; but that's definitely not recommended, since if nothing else it is liable to break badly in new versions of latexmk.pl.

Comment: 1. For a script that is to work cross platform, I would write a perl script, not a shell script.  2. Yes, this feature is something I would consider for a future release. Something more general than the current possibilities would clearly be useful for a number of situations.